# Why when I use vaadin select data stay visible after delete but if I use simple select, data deleted from UI correctly

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

Why using renderer directive, my select won't open. Renderer importings

correctly from another file.

What can be the cause of this problem?
I also add my dependency webpack list that can be cause of problem

```
import {renderer} from './renderer'

constructor() {
    super()
      
    this.allScripts2 = [{'name':3,'id':2}]
}
    
<vaadin-select @change="${(e) => this.chooseCurrentScript(e)}"
    value="${this.currentScript && this.currentScript.name ? this.currentScript.name : 'Choose type'}">
        ${renderer(this.allScripts2, () => html`
            <template>
                <vaadin-list-box>
                    ${this.allScripts2.map(el => html`
                        <vaadin-item id="${el.id}">${el.name}</vaadin-item>
                    `)}
                </vaadin-list-box>
            </template>
        `)}
</vaadin-select>


my dependency webpack list
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@vaadin/router": "^1.1.0",
    "@vaadin/vaadin-combo-box": "^5.4.1",
    "@vaadin/vaadin-tabs": "^3.2.0",
    "@vaadin/vaadin-text-field": "^2.8.1",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "knex": "^0.21.6",
    "lit-html": "^0.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.12",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
    "pwa-helpers": "^0.8.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are mixing the `lit-html` and `Polymer` templates.

Usage of the renderer directive would be a solution for this case.

Please take a look onto the example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/vaadin-lit-renderer-experiment?path=app.js%3A41%3A0

Comment: I use this derective, but select dont open. I update my question. I really need your help with renderer

Comment: and when I use your example in my project select dont open, looks like flicker

Comment: pls check my dependency webpack list above